# (in R) how to arrange column A based on column B

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, arrange-act-assert

I got a data frame like this:

| Factory | Bread |
| --- | --- |
| A | a |
| A | a |
| B | c |
| B | b |
| B | d |
| C | a |
| D | e |

I want to find **name of the factory with the most number of bread**

I write two codes and got different answers.

1.

```
df %>%
  group_by(factory, bread)%>%
  summarise(n = n())%>%
  arrange(desc(n))
```

2. 

```
df %>% 
  group_by(factory) %>% 
  mutate(number = length(unique(bread)))%>% 
  arrange(desc(number))
```

May I ask which one is the right code and why?

Thank you!!!!

Comment: Do you want `df %>% group_by(factory) %>% summarise(n = n_distinct(bread))`

Comment: It works!!!! but now I got three different results for this question. May I ask wether there are some problems with the code I wrote before?

Comment: Your second code is similar to mine i.e `length(unique` is `n_distinct`, but you created that as a column with `mutate`, where as I summarised with a single row per group.  The first code in your post is basically giving the count of each combinations

Answer (score 3):

We could use `n_distinct` from `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(factory)%>%
    summarise(bread = n_distinct(bread))
```

Output:

```
  factory bread
  <chr>   <int>
1 A           2
2 B           1
3 C           1
```

Comment: Thank Tarjae!  But may I ask why the code I wrote are both wrong.

Comment: `n_distinct` is best for these purposes. your code is not wrong!

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` option

```
> setorder(setDT(df)[, .(Bread = uniqueN(Bread)), Factory], -Bread)[]
   Factory Bread
1:       B     3
2:       A     1
3:       C     1
4:       D     1
```